# Reactjs - Preselecting options with react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using the react-select select box to allow the user to select multiple options from a dropdown menu.  I was wondering if it's possible to preselect a few options (already have the selectbox populated).  I've created a sandbox for the project:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-almeida-4iux6

This is the dashboard that calls the SelectBox, in the state I have the "preselectedOptions" which are the options I would like already selected.  In this example I would like to have "Option 1" and "Option 3" already selected:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SelectBox from "./dropdown";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentOptions: [],
      preselectedOptions: ["Option 1", "Option 3"]
    };
  }

  updateOptions(selected) {
    this.setState({
      currentOptions: selected
    });
  }

  showSelected() {
    alert(this.state.currentOptions.length + " selected");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectBox selectedOptions={this.updateOptions.bind(this)} />
        <br />

        <button onClick={() => this.showSelected()}>Selected</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

And here is the SelectBox:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

class SelectBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.customStyles = {
      input: styles => {
        return {
          ...styles,
          height: "45px"
        };
      }
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.options = [];

    this.options.push({ value: "Option 1", label: "Option 1" });
    this.options.push({ value: "Option 2", label: "Option 2" });
    this.options.push({ value: "Option 3", label: "Option 3" });
    this.options.push({ value: "Option 4", label: "Option 4" });
    this.options.push({ value: "Option 5", label: "Option 5" });
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.selectedOptions(e);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          isMulti
          maxMenuHeight="150px"
          styles={this.customStyles}
          options={this.options}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          className="basic-multi-select"
          classNamePrefix="select"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SelectBox;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the `defaultValue` prop.

```
<Select
  isMulti
  maxMenuHeight="150px"
  styles={this.customStyles}
  options={this.options}
  defaultValue={[this.options[0], this.options[2]]}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  className="basic-multi-select"
  classNamePrefix="select"
/>
```

Here's a link to a modified sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-goldberg-lpr6w?fontsize=14

Good luck!

Comment: No problems. Kudos to @dacre-denny who delivered the same answer a few minutes faster than me.

Answer (score 2):

use the `preselectedOptions` as `defaultProps` in the select props

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the [`defaultValue`](https://react-select.com/props#statemanager-props) prop.

So for example, to have `Option 1` and `Option 2` pre-selected, you would pass both of those in an array via `defaultValue` like so:

```
{/* Pass array of preselected options to defaultValue */}
<Select
      isMulti
      defaultValue={[this.options[0], this.options[1]]}
      maxMenuHeight="150px"
      styles={this.customStyles}
      options={this.options}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      className="basic-multi-select"
      classNamePrefix="select"
    />
```